# How can extract 30 seconds of audio from smaller/larger file on 30 seconds using ffmpeg

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg, command

I have try to extract 30 second audio using ffmpeg, its working fine in case of sample file is larger then 30 second. but in case of file is 15 second then it will return only 15 second.

Here shows my code

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -ss 0 -i sample.mp3 -t 30 output.mp3");
?>
```

I want to extract 30 second audio from 15 second sample file.

Thanks.

Comment: ... what? You want to repeat the 15x2 to get the 30 seconds or just no sound for the remaining 15 seconds?

Comment: I want to repeat, Example if sample file 22 second then i want  : 22+8 = 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use stream_loop.

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -ss 0 -i sample.mp3 -t 30 output.mp3
```

In my quick test, the output duration is correct, but the duration displayed by player is wrong,

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya, it's working and show correct duration on player.